# SessionListener for session modification in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I am looking for a way to monitor what kind of data is stored in sessions.
I know there is session listener which has methods called when session is created or destroyed but what about session modification?
Is there any listener to run when data in sessions in modified, ex. when adding new value or modifying old one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement HttpSessionAttributeListener and add its entry into web.xml . It has methods like attrubuteAdded,attrubuteRemoved and attrubuteReplaced.

```
public class MyAttributeListener implements HttpSessionAttributeListener {

@Override
public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
    String attributeName = event.getName();
    Object attributeValue = event.getValue();
    System.out.println("Attribute added : " + attributeName + " : " + attributeValue);
}

@Override
public void attributeRemoved(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
    String attributeName = event.getName();
    Object attributeValue = event.getValue();
    System.out.println("Attribute removed : " + attributeName + " : " + attributeValue);
}

@Override
public void attributeReplaced(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
    String attributeName = event.getName();
    Object attributeValue = event.getValue();
    System.out.println("Attribute replaced : " + attributeName + " : " + attributeValue);   
}
```

}

Add entry to web.xml like this

```
<web-app ...>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>com.myapp.MyAttributeListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [HttpSessionAttributeListener](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionAttributeListener.html)

> This listener interface can be implemented in order to get notifications of changes to the attribute lists of sessions within this web application.

Please, note that while it could notify you about new objects getting bound or removed; it won't notify changes done to properties or elements of an already bound object (say, if you add another element to an `ArrayList`). It would however notify if the `ArrayLlist is *replaced*.

```
public class SessionModifcationListener implements HttpSessionAttributeListener {

    @Override
    public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent se) {

    }

    @Override
    public void attributeRemoved(HttpSessionBindingEvent se) {

    }

    @Override
    public void attributeReplaced(HttpSessionBindingEvent se) {

    }

}
```